# Importing RSA Key from file

Tags: file, import, rsa, aspnet-regiis.exe

Getting an error "Safe handle has been closed" while try to Importing RSA Keys from file.

The following command I have used in Visual Studio 2022 command prompt

```
aspnet_regiis -pi "keyname" "C:\keyfile.xml"
```

Anyone know how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

There is a section about this issue on this blog
https://austrianalex.com/rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider-not-recommended-for-children-under-5.html
It involves ensuring permissions on the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA are correct

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587